# How to create blur background when fab is clicked?

Tags: java, android, background, blur, floating-action-button

I'm new in developing android application.
I have troubles with creating blurred background when extended (floating) action button is pressed.

I've been looking for a solution for days, however nothing works :(
I've tried to use blurred view layer underneath my buttons, but it doesn't work correctly.

I've also tried to use setOnMenuToggleListener or setOnFloatingActionsMenuUpdateListener, but android studio doesn't recognize these functions.

Can anyone help with my question?

In my XML file i use these types:

```
com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
```

```
com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
```

I wanna have result like this
[one result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyQPo.png)
or this
[another variant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBLjX.png)

Comment: Hi, Please avoid using links for images/code. Link may one day become broken, making your question useless for future users.

Comment: @gioravered
i've tried to fix it, the problem is that i've just created my profile here and i have not enough points in "reputation" to post image(

Comment: Ok, please add you XML and your attempt to add a "blur view"